# Как мне использовать функцию на двух классах?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

У меня есть вот такой код

```
class Radio(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, icon, size, margin, parent=None):
        super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)
        change_color(self)
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=QtGui.QColor("red"),  
            endValue=QtGui.QColor("white"), 
            valueChanged=self._on_value_changed,
            duration=400,
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(QtGui.QColor("blue"), QtGui.QColor("black")) 
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


    def _on_value_changed(self, color):
        foreground = (
            QtGui.QColor("yellow")  
            if self._animation.direction() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            else QtGui.QColor("green") 
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(color, foreground)


    def _update_stylesheet(self, background, foreground):
        self.setStyleSheet(
        """
            background-color: %s;
            color: %s;
        """
            % (background.name(), foreground.name())
        )

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().leaveEvent(event)


class Label(QLabel): 
    def __init__(self, icon, size, margin, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        change_color(self)
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=QtGui.QColor("red"),  
            endValue=QtGui.QColor("white"), 
            valueChanged=self._on_value_changed,
            duration=400,
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(QtGui.QColor("blue"), QtGui.QColor("black")) 
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


    def _on_value_changed(self, color):
        foreground = (
            QtGui.QColor("yellow")  
            if self._animation.direction() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            else QtGui.QColor("green")  
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(color, foreground)


    def _update_stylesheet(self, background, foreground):
        self.setStyleSheet(
        """
            background-color: %s;
            color: %s;
        """
            % (background.name(), foreground.name())
        )

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().leaveEvent(event)
```

И я хочу написать функцию чтобы сократить код

```
def color(self):
    def face_init(self):
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=QtGui.QColor("red"),  
            endValue=QtGui.QColor("white"),  
            valueChanged=self._on_value_changed,
            duration=400,
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(QtGui.QColor("blue"), QtGui.QColor("black"))  
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


    def _on_value_changed(self, color):
        foreground = (
            QtGui.QColor("yellow")  
            if self._animation.direction() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            else QtGui.QColor("green")  
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(color, foreground)


    def _update_stylesheet(self, background, foreground):
        self.setStyleSheet(
        """
            background-color: %s;
            color: %s;
        """
            % (background.name(), foreground.name())
        )

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().leaveEvent(event)

class Radio(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, icon, size, margin, parent=None):
        super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)
        color(self)

class Label(QLabel): 
    def __init__(self, icon, size, margin, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        color(self)
```

Но проблема в том что я все еще плохо знаю как работать с классами.
Я могу обработать только то что находится внутри одного метода

```
def color(self):
    self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
        startValue=QtGui.QColor("red"), 
        endValue=QtGui.QColor("white"), 
        valueChanged=self._on_value_changed,
        duration=400,
    )
    return self
```

Но как запихнуть в функцию все методы _on_value_changed, _update_stylesheet,enterEvent,leaveEvent.
Я не знаю.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Нужно сначала язык изучить, а потом браться за фреймворки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это типичная задача ООП -- наследование.

Оформляйте `color` как класс от `QWidget` и указываете его предком для `Radio` и `Label`.

Пример:

```
class MyColor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.face_init()

    def face_init(self):
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=QtGui.QColor("red"),
            endValue=QtGui.QColor("white"),
            valueChanged=self._on_value_changed,
            duration=400,
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(QtGui.QColor("blue"), QtGui.QColor("black"))
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))

    def _on_value_changed(self, color):
        foreground = (
            QtGui.QColor("yellow")
            if self._animation.direction() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            else QtGui.QColor("green")
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(color, foreground)

    def _update_stylesheet(self, background, foreground):
        self.setStyleSheet(
        """
            background-color: %s;
            color: %s;
        """
            % (background.name(), foreground.name())
        )

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().leaveEvent(event)


class Radio(QRadioButton, MyColor):
    def __init__(self, icon, size, margin, parent=None):
        super().__init__()


class Label(QLabel, MyColor):
    def __init__(self, icon, size, margin, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
```

Пример запуска

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QRadioButton, QLabel, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui

...

app = QApplication([])

b = Radio(1, 2, 3)
b.setText('[Button] Hello World!')
b.show()

l = Label(1, 2, 3)
l.setText('[Label] Hello World!')
l.show()

app.exec()
```

---

**PS.**

Для отлова ошибок советую использовать `sys.excepthook`. Пока отлаживал ответ, мне очень пригодилось.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/467888458d54a3572df6a9d6e5889fe1cd04635e/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L24)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

...

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

...

app = QApplication([])
```

Comment: Значит можно поставить два наследования. Хорошо а как тогда передовать переменные между ними? `class MyColor(QWidget):
 def __init__(self, test, parent=None):
  super().__init__(parent)
  print(test)

class Radio(QRadioButton, MyColor): 
 def __init__(self, test, parent=None):
  super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)

b = Radio('TEXT')`

Comment: @orlatym, или сделайте метод/поле для переменной и вызывайте в конструкторе `Radio` (мне кажется это хороший вариант), либо передавайте в конструктор `super()`: `Radio` в `super().__init__(test, parent)`

Comment: Ну второй вариант я понял. Он работает. А первый я не совсем понял. Можете обяснить? мне просто любопытно.

Comment: В `MyColor` создаете метод `def setTest(self, test): print(test)`, а в конструкторе `Radio`: его вызываете `self.setTest(test)`, тогда можно убрать `test` из конструктора `MyColor` и не передавать его в `super()` у `Radio`